# How to share data between components using a service properly?

Tags: angular

I am learning angular2 and was able to share data between sibling components using input/output.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zW5c8d1HJQ32qJtCHTTS?p=info) is my working example.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrotherComponent} from './brother.component'
import {SisterComponent} from './sister.component'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <brother (onChange)="handleBrotherEvent($event)" [dataFromSister]="dataFromSister"></brother>
      <sister (onChange)="handleSisterEvent($event)" [dataFromBrother]="dataFromBrother"></sister>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  handleBrotherEvent(data)
  {
    this.dataFromBrother = data;
    console.log("called from handleBrotherEvent in app", data); 
  }

  handleSisterEvent(data)
  {
    this.dataFromSister = data;
    console.log("called from sister handleSisterEvent in app", data); 
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, BrotherComponent, SisterComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Now I want to learn about services and see how I can share my data through that. I have tried to look at the angular.io documentation to understand communication between components using a service, but I am still confused on how to get this working with my example. Here is the section I have been reading:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

I am looking for a concrete example to convert my original example to share component form data using a service. Is there somebody that can help me?

**Update:**

Based off the below comments, I changed my plnkr to this. Hopefully this is how its supposed to work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zW5c8d1HJQ32qJtCHTTS?p=preview

Comment: So what is the problem, just create common service in this subtree which implements rxjs/subject, inject it into both components and that's it. Documentation is very clear.

Comment: @dfsq would I need to create an subject object for each component? I want to be able to share data both from both components.

Comment: @skone the shared state should be in your service and the components access it from there

Comment: @rob. Ok. So in my case I would push the entire form data into the service from component 1, I guess? If you can modify my example, that would be great. I am sure a lot of users would benefit from it.

Comment: I'm not writing a full answer because it won't reply exactly to your answer but you may want to take a look to a redux/reactive architecture. With angular2, the best one (according to me) is ngrx. But it's gonna be for sure a huge step if you haven't heard about redux and rxjs. Maybe for later but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: @Maxime. Thanks. I will take a look at that.

Comment: @skone if you're interested by this kind of state management, I'd recommend you to read the Tour Of Heroes app rebuilt using ngrx [here](http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/) and [this](https://github.com/teropa/harmonics-explorer) repo from Teropa which is really excellent. They both helped me a lot.

Comment: @Maxime. Sweet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can always just create a binding to a variable on a service from two different components. In this example one component increments a number and the other component displays the value

[image]

You won't be able to detect and respond to changes with this approach. A more robust approach would be to use an observable to broadcast changes to the state in your service. e.g.

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject"

export class MyService {
    private state$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('initialState');

    changeState(myChange) {
        this.state$.next(myChange);
    }

    getState() {
        return this.state$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then your components could subscribe to state changes and change the state by calling custom methods on the service. I have a concrete example of this approach here https://github.com/robianmcd/ng2-redux-demo/blob/redux-demo-with-service/app/user.service.ts

Comment: I changed my plnkr and got it working. Can you see anything wrong with that? http://plnkr.co/edit/zW5c8d1HJQ32qJtCHTTS?p=preview

Comment: will it work if my sender component, receiver component and service are in different directories?

Comment: Hi Rob, can you please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60558588/how-to-access-variables-of-one-component-in-another-component-angular/60558804?noredirect=1#comment107137586_60558804

Comment: Hope this will help you out, to understand properly >  https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

and there is section named `Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service`