# Unable to pass data between two angular 4 component using Angular service

Tags: angular, components, angular-services

Unable to pass data from one angular component to another using service. Here is the service code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public serviceData: string;
}
```

Here is the component `home`:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { DataService } from '../common/common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(public router: Router, public commonService: DataService) {
    this.commonService.serviceData = 'Message from Home Component to App Component!';
    this.router.navigate(["overview"]);
  }

}
```

Here is the overview component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../common/common.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.css']
})
export class OverviewComponent {
  constructor(public messageService: DataService) {
    alert(this.messageService.serviceData);
  }
}
```

The alert in the `OverviewComponent` always shows `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components using a service properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly)

Comment: A service is meant to be a singleton, which is a single instance of a class. Since it is a singleton, it can keep one set of any data and share it across components. In order to ensure a service is a singleton, it must be registered ONLY ONE TIME. You are registering it twice by adding it to the `[providers]` array of both components. The recommended technique is to register it with the App Module, as shown here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have injected `DataService` provider on component level that instance will be shared to descendant injector tree from current component. So in this case you had `DataService` instance of `app-home` & `app-overview` will be different in other words Angular will create two different instance for `DataService`.

Recommended practice is to register sharable data providers on root module `providers` metadata option so that every consumer will access to same instance. Make sure you remove the `DataService` from component level `providers` metadata option.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  providers: [DataService, ...], //<- moved here
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: Tried the same but still unable to pass data. It's showing undefined

Comment: Did you follow the answer above AND remove  'providers: [DataService]' from both components ?

Comment: @DeanChalk yes I did remove provider from both the components

Comment: @iJade and where are you providing the service now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use rxjs subject. Create new rxjs subject in your service like this

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    myNewSubject = new Subject<any>();

    informDataChanges(passyourobject){
      this.myNewSubject.next(passyourobject);
  }
```

}

When change happens in your component or you want to pass data to another component simply call this service function from your component and pass data as parameter to this function. You can do that with something like this

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-some',
      templateUrl: './some.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./some.component.css']
    })
    export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor( private myService: MyService) { }

      someFunction(){
        this.myService.informLogout('somedata');//Passing data to service here
      }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Now all you need to do is subscribe to that data in another component. IMPORTANT subject keeps on watches any changes to it, and data will be continuous stream and it will be automatically subscribed. So it is best to subscribe to the subject in the constructor, and changes will be immediately reflected in that component.

You do it with some thing like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-another',
          templateUrl: './another.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./another.component.css']
        })
        export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor( private myService: MyService) {
            this.myService.myNewSubject.subscribe(data=>{
             console.log(data);
       }) 
}
```

This way you can pass data between any number of components easily.