# Send data from 1st component to 2nd component Angular

Tags: angular

this is my 1st component

```
     @Component({
        selector: 'app-amount',
        template: `
         <h3>Amount component</h3>
        <form #f = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
         <input type="number" name="number" ngModel id="number">
         <button type='submit'>Add</button>
          </form>

    <div *ngFor="let item of numberArray" >{{item}}</div>

    <div>Total: {{total}}</div>
      `
    })
    export class Amount  {
      @Output () total = new EventEmitter<number>();
      @ViewChild('') submitForm: NgForm;
      numberArray = [];


      constructor(){

      }
      onSubmit(form: NgForm){
        const total = 0;
        this.numberArray.push(form.value.number);
        this.total = this.numberArray.reduce((prev: number, next: number)=>{
          //this.total.emit(prev + next);
          return prev + next;
        })
      }
    }
```

This is the 2nd component

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'app-total',
     template: `
     <h3>Total component</h3>
     <span>I want the Total value appear here. What is the best way to implment/get?</span>
     <p></p>
     `,
    styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
    })
   export class Total  {

     totalValue;
     total(number: number){
     this.totalValue = number;
   }
   }
```

I can get the Sum value of Input box from 1st component but cannot send it to 2nd component. I tried to use Output but it didn't work. Where am I wrong?
Here is my stackblitz link code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-value-from-other-component?file=app%2Ftotal.component.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components using a service properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly)

Comment: I tried to use Output but it didn't work. I don't know where am I wrong

Comment: you'll need a Service to share data between components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is updated
https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-value-from-other-component-tsbko6?file=app%2Famount.component.ts

You were using the event emitter incorrectly. Secondly, in your app component you were not subscribing to the event and then you needed to pass that value as an input to the second component.