# Sharing data between components using service is not working (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have two components, the first one is called `product` and the second one is called `product-details`.

I want to click on `product` to navigate to `product-details`` component (the two components are not displayed in the same page).

I created a service which is called `sessionService` to pass the data between those two components. I viewed multiple solutions and tried this one :

[How to share data between components using a service properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly) but it's not working.

**Here is session service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {IProduct} from "./product";
import { BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {

  private product = new BehaviorSubject<IProduct>({name:'asd',id:3,image:"asas",price:"asd"});
  currentProduct = this.product.asObservable();
  changeProduct(product:IProduct){
    console.log("shit");
    this.product.next(product);
  }

  constructor() {}

}
```

**And here is product component:**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IProduct} from "../product";
import {SessionService} from "../session.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'ec-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product:IProduct;
  @Input() productShape:string;
  constructor(private sessionService:SessionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  goToProductDetails(){
    window.location.href = "product";
    this.sessionService.changeProduct(this.product);
  }
}
```

**And here is product template:**

```
<div class="prod-ver" *ngIf="productShape==='vertical'" (click)="goToProductDetails()">
  <figure class="fig-ver"><img [src]="product.image" alt="product"></figure>
  <div class="p-name">{{product.name}}</div>
  <div class="p-price">{{product.price}}</div>
</div>
```

**product details component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {IProduct} from "../product";
import {SessionService} from "../session.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'ec-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  productId:number;
  products:IProduct[];
  product:IProduct;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private sessionService:SessionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.currentProduct.subscribe(
      product => {
        this.product = product;
        console.log(this.product);
      }
    );
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: are u using rxjs?

Comment: ya , i'm using BehaviourSubject from rxjs

Comment: ok so for start you should't be using window.location.href , that's why you have angular router.

Comment: I believe window.href will reload the App, so your subscriptions will be destroyed, use angular router instead..

Comment: Using a service (using a BejaviourSubject) need that the two components are at time in the aplication. Else you can use a simple variable that belong to the service and using getter/setter in each component. (NOTE: think about @jetset solucion too). there're a lot of examples about use a variable, you can see my stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrv6hs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice I would pass the ID of the product alongside the request to the detail page and then load up the product using a [resolver](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267).

Alternatively, I would suggest using the angular router instead of `window.location.href = "product";` That way the page won't refresh and the state that is being stored in your service should persist. Make sure to include the `import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';` into your app.module.ts.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {IProduct} from "../product";
import {SessionService} from "../session.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'ec-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product:IProduct;
  @Input() productShape:string;
  constructor(
    private sessionService:SessionService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  goToProductDetails(){
    this.router.navigate(['/product']);
    this.sessionService.changeProduct(this.product);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , the window.location.href is the problem