# Angular interaction between components using filter pipe

Tags: angular, filter, components, pipe, interaction

Am using custom pipe for filter and display the table, it's working fine when the filter text box and table are in the same component, but I wanted filter to be global so that i can apply that filter to any table, but i don't know how to make interaction between components, as am new to angular. any help will be apprciated thank you. Ahh...one more thing, am using angular 7

Comment: As am new to angular, so am expecting a solution particularly components interaction using pipe

Comment: Can you help us out with a [Minimal Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating your use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components using a service properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly)

Comment: And also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-px9hwy

Comment: I just added a minimal code, which is not in working condition, hope you would get a fair idea what am trying to do.. TIA