# passing array through service between two unrelated components

Tags: angular

So I am setting an array in component A

```
    this.passingService.setArray(this.array);
```

and retrieving it in component B

```
    this.passingService.getArray();
```

this is how my passing service looks like:

passingService.ts

```
    data: any;
    set(array){
            this.data = array;
    }
    get(){
            return this.data;
    }
```

the method in componentA where the data is being set is called every 5 minutes. And the data may or may not get updated. I need to pass the updated data from A to B.

I tried setting the data directly through variable too

```
    this.passingService.data = this.arrayA; //component A

    this.arrayB = this.passingService.array; //componentB
```

this is how my passing service looks like:

passingService.ts

```
    data: any;
```

I'm not getting the updated data in real time. I'm able to see it after reloading the application. I need the updated data in real time.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between components using a service properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an observable instead to emit changes and then subscribe in  component B so your service will look like

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

dataSource=new EventEmitter<any>();
```

then in your component b

```
this.passingService.dataSource.subscribe((data)=>{this.arrayB=data});
```

in your component a whenever your data change

```
this.passingService.dataSource.emit(this.arrayA);
```