# Passing Array to another page using Path

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a html page which contains an array called students. I would like to pass this array over to another page, when a button is pressed. Is this possible? I can only do it with one variable at the moment.

Below is my module code for the path (passing over one variable):

```
 {
    path: 'new-page/:IDvariable',
    loadChildren: './new-page/new-page.module#NewPageModule'
  }
```

Below is my html code for the button which takes the user to the new page:

```
<a
  routerLink="/new-page/{{ IDvariable }}"
  class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-success mr-1"
  >Navigate to New Page</a
>
```

Does anyone know whether I can pass a students array over, with the IDvariable?

Comment: You can convert your array to string and then pass it in your element's data attribute.

Comment: Thanks @ZainShabir Could you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible, but you can't do this with path.

To share data between components, you can create a service to keep data saved. So when you click on button you have to update Service with data, then, after navigate, you pick up this data and show in your new component.

[Here is an awnser explain with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468172/how-to-share-data-between-components-using-a-service-properly#answer-40468721)

Answer (score 0):

Although, there is a way by using query parameters or the router state, I would consider using a service. This is much easier to implement and can be maintained.

- StudentService
- PageAComponent
- PageBComponent

Both components inject the StudentSerivice - now there is no need to pass an array in the router parameters because both components use the same reference to the array.